# Android Proximity Sensor Not Working

Tags: android, proximity

I had a great working proximity code which is broken just after I've changed the targetSdkVersion from 11 to 19. I didn't change anything else at all.

I wonder if there is anybody faced this issue before. Or is this sort of a known issue.

Regards

Comment: what sort of error are you facing now can you post the logcat please ?

Comment: I don't get any errors actually. Screen went off once when I get close to the phone(which is expected)but never come back again unless I push power button. As I said I've changed nothing else but targetsdkversion. Let me check the logcat again.

Comment: yes check your logcat it will show you something ...

Comment: It was hard to diff both situations but I guess in the broken version(in which I increase the targetSdkVersion to 19) I saw "Caller does not have DEVICE_POWER permission". This could mean something perhaps.

Comment: yes that means you have to add android.permission.DEVICE_POWER in your android menifest file under <uses-sdk tag before <application tag but you have to make your app as a system app in order to work this permission ... I don't know weather android has restricted the access to proximity in sdk 19 or what ...

Comment: You mean <uses-permission> right? I did this but no change. It's happenning for all targetSdkVersion values > 10(11,12...19) but working fine with 10,9,8..

Comment: yes i meant that ... I worked on it some time ago by setting minsdkversion = 9 and targetsdkversion = 19 and it worked for me but I don't understand how it can give this DEVICE_POWER error ....

Comment: have you set that DEVICE_POWER permission?

Comment: nope no permission ...

Answer (score 0):

zgulser I don't know how much work did you do on the sensor but this is the introductory code for the proximity sensor that I tried hope this helps you..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    TextView tVProximity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        tVProximity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tVProximity);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor proximitySensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
        if (proximitySensor == null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Proximity Sensor Found!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Uri notification = 
            RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
            r.play();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, 
        sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY){
            if(event.values[0]==0){
                tVProximity.setText("You are Near: "+String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
                try {
                    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
                    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                    r.play();
                    // r.stop();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                tVProximity.setText("You are Far: "+String.valueOf(event.values[0]));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The formatting on your answer is seriously messed up. Could you edit your answer to make the code more readable?

Comment: Hey Darkie. This is pretty much the same with mine and I suppose with others. I still didn't get why I get this error when I changed the targetSDKVersion.

Comment: @zgulser you are getting this error on this code also ?

Comment: No. The problem is not about the sensor or it's callback. The problem is in locking/unlocking the screen using the PowerManager & PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK thing.